# How to loop through CommandButton on Sheet1 with For next loop

Tags: excel, vba

So I want to set Caption on Command buttons according to A1 to D1 strings in sheet3

```
Dim buttonname as String
Dim i as Integer

For i = 1 to 5 
buttonname = "Commandbutton" & i

buttonname.Caption = Worksheets(sheet3).Cells(1,i)

Next
```

It looks like this code is not working, need to be Controls but when I tried with Controls I can not set it to change command buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buttonname` is a String, not an Object.  You first need to find the Object, and then change the Caption / Text

This will, however, vary based on whether you are using a Form Control, or an ActiveX Control:

```
'ActiveX Control
Worksheets("sheet3").OLEObjects(i).Object.Caption = buttonname
'Form Control
Worksheets("sheet3").Shapes(i).OLEFormat.Object.text
```

Comment: To be honest I don't get this? Should I change buttonname to Object? And I am using ActiveX  Control

Comment: @jure Try `Worksheets("sheet3").OLEObjects(buttonname).Object.Caption = Worksheets(sheet3).Cells(1,i).Value` to set the Caption of the `OLEObject` with the name stored in `buttonanme` to the value stored in Row `i`, Column 1

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of many, loop all shapes in the worksheet, check for buttons, rename.

```
Sub listButtons()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim row As Long
    For Each shp In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes
        If shp.Name Like "Button*" Then
            row = row + 1
            shp.OLEFormat.Object.Text = Range("A" & row).Value
        End If
        'Select Case as an Alternative to the If approach
        Select Case shp.Name
            Case "Button 2"
                shp.OLEFormat.Object.Text = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
            Case "Button 3"
                shp.OLEFormat.Object.Text = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value
            Case Else
                'Do nothing if not Button 2 or 3
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: How will I know witch button I am on. I want to address CommandButton2 to be from A2 and so on.

Comment: `shp.Name` will give you the button name, usually Button 2 will be CommandButton2, and so on. So you can do a `Select Case` instead of the If